# Python: can't work If JSON response is empty

Tags: python, json, loops, opencv

i'm just try platerecognizer.com API to detect rectangle box and recognize each character inside the box(license plate). but the API can't read video file, they just receive jpeg/jpg file and then generate the JSON. so i split the video each frame and send to API and i've done with this.

i have this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import glob
import argparse
import requests
from PIL import Image
import json
import time
import math
import cv2
import os
import json

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("assets/car-number-plate.mp4")
    frameRate = cap.get(5)
    print(frameRate)
    seconds=2
    multiplier=frameRate*seconds
    x=1
    while (cap.isOpened()):                                            
            frameId = int(round(cap.get(1)))
            print(frameId)
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if (ret != True):
                break
            result = []
            if (frameId % multiplier == 0):
                filename = 'output_frame/frameId' +  str(int(x)) + ".jpg"
                cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
                time.sleep(1)
                path = "/home/mycomputer/Documents/platerecognizer-test/%s" % filename
                with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
                    response = requests.post(
                    'https://api.platerecognizer.com/v1/plate-reader/',
                    files=dict(upload=fp),
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'MY_API_KEY'})
                    result.append(response.json())
                    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2));
                    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(result, outfile)
                os.remove("%s" %filename)
                x+=1
                time.sleep(1)

                resp_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
                num=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['plate']
                boxs=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['box']
                xmins,ymins,ymaxs,xmaxs=boxs['xmin'],boxs['ymin'],boxs['ymax'],boxs['xmax']

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmins, ymins), (xmaxs, ymaxs), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame,num,(xmins, ymins-10), font, 1,(0, 255, 0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.imshow("plat nomor yang terdeteksi",frame)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                print(f"mobil dengan plat nomor: {num}")
    cap.release()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

how the code above work? so, first i'm load video from dir, split them by frame, send them to API, receive full(not empty) response JSON from API like this:

```
[
  {
    "processing_time": 102.465,
    "results": [
      {
        "box": {
          "xmin": 537,
          "ymin": 346,
          "xmax": 657,
          "ymax": 407
        },
        "plate": "b1399ere",
        "region": {
          "score": 0.876,
          "code": "id"
        },
        "vehicle": {
          "score": 0.802,
          "box": {
            "xmin": 163,
            "ymin": 12,
            "xmax": 709,
            "ymax": 472
          },
          "type": "Car"
        },
        "score": 0.898,
        "candidates": [
          {
            "score": 0.898,
            "plate": "b1399ere"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.791,
            "plate": "bi399ere"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.79,
            "plate": "81399ere"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.683,
            "plate": "8i399ere"
          }
        ],
        "dscore": 0.732
      }
    ],
    "filename": "0243_tzJBu_frameId7.jpg",
    "version": 1,
    "camera_id": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-04-20T02:43:34.123444Z"
  }
]
```

the code is working well when they find result from json API that we sent image before, but when the code find JSON response with empty result like this:

```
[
  {
    "processing_time": 82.204,
    "results": [],
    "filename": "0243_aKa1u_frameId8.jpg",
    "version": 1,
    "camera_id": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-04-20T02:43:38.881827Z"
  }
]
```

i just stuck with this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

i want to make this loop work if result JSON is empty, and then back to regenerate the next captured frame above, and get JSON response with full result. but, how to do that loops?

thankyou

Comment: This error is observed, just because you are trying to access an empty list. Since this is a loop, just add a condition to continue if resp_dict[0]['results'] == []: continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is accessing the results can be put inside a condition to use the results only if the result has elements.

```
if resp_dict[0]['results']:
        num=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['plate']
        boxs=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['box']
                    xmins,ymins,ymaxs,xmaxs=boxs['xmin'],boxs['ymin'],boxs['ymax'],boxs['xmax']
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmins, ymins), (xmaxs, ymaxs), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame,num,(xmins, ymins-10), font, 1,(0, 255, 0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("plat nomor yang terdeteksi",frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(f"mobil dengan plat nomor: {num}")
```